# terraform Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/name-secret": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

i have trouble in gitlab ci, when am executing `terraform apply` locally all is ok(kubectl is working correctly in gitlab ci container and locally), but in executing the same script in gitlab ci throws error that showed below

terraform version locally `v0.12.24`

terraform version in gitlab ci container `v0.12.25`

main.tf

```
provider "google" {
  project = "profiline-russia"
  region  = "us-central1"
  zone    = "us-central1-c"
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name     = "main-cluster"
  location = "europe-west3"

  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count = 1
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary_nodes" {
  name       = "node-pool"
  location   = "europe-west3"
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.primary.name
  node_count = 1

  node_config {
    machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
  }
}


# dashboard ui
# module "kubernetes_dashboard" {
#   source = "cookielab/dashboard/kubernetes"
#   version = "0.9.0"

#   kubernetes_namespace_create = true
#   kubernetes_dashboard_csrf = "random-string"
# }


# deployment server
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "deployment-server" {
  metadata {
    name = var.data-deployment-server.metadata.name
    labels = {
      App = var.data-deployment-server.labels.App
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        App = var.data-deployment-server.labels.App
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          App = var.data-deployment-server.labels.App
        }
      }

      spec {
        container {
          image = var.data-deployment-server.image.name # for passing this i made gcr public
          name = var.data-deployment-server.container.name
          command = var.data-deployment-server.container.command
          port {
            container_port = var.data-deployment-server.container.port
          }
          env {
            name  = "ENV"
            value = "production"
          }
          env {
            name  = "DB_USERNAME"
            value_from {
              secret_key_ref {
                name = kubernetes_secret.secret-db.metadata.0.name
                key = "db_username"
              }
            }
          }
          env {
            name  = "DB_PASSWORD"
            value_from {
              secret_key_ref {
                name = kubernetes_secret.secret-db.metadata.0.name
                key = "db_password"
              }
            }
          }
          env {
            name  = "DB_NAME"
            value_from {
              secret_key_ref {
                name = kubernetes_secret.secret-db.metadata.0.name
                key = "db_name"
              }
            }
          }
          env {
            name  = "DEFAULT_BUCKET_NAME"
            value = var.default-bucket-name
          }
          env {
            name  = "DATABASE_ClOUD_SQL_NAME"
            value = var.database-cloud-sql-name
          }
          env {
            name  = "PROJECT_GCP_ID"
            value = var.project-gcp-id
          }
          env {
            name  = "K8S_SA_CLOUD_STORAGE"
            value_from {
              secret_key_ref {
                name = kubernetes_secret.secret-sa-cloud-storage.metadata.0.name
                key = "sa-cloud-storage.json"
              }
            }
          }
          env {
            name = "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
            value = "/app/secrets/sa-cloud-storage.json"
          }

          liveness_probe {
            http_get {
              path = "/swagger"
              port = var.data-deployment-server.container.port
            }

            initial_delay_seconds = 10
            period_seconds = 10
          }
        }

        container {
          image = var.data-cloud-sql-proxy.image.name
          name  = var.data-cloud-sql-proxy.container.name
          command = var.data-cloud-sql-proxy.container.command
          volume_mount {
            name = var.data-cloud-sql-proxy.volume.name
            mount_path = "/secrets/"
            read_only = true
          }
        }

        volume {
          name = var.data-cloud-sql-proxy.volume.name
          secret {
            secret_name = kubernetes_secret.secret-gsa.metadata.0.name
          }
        }
      }


    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "service-server" { # wget http://name-service-server:8000/swagger
  metadata {
    name = var.data-deployment-server.service.name
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      App = var.data-deployment-server.labels.App
    }
    port {
      port = var.data-deployment-server.container.port
    }

    type = var.data-deployment-server.service.type
  }
}


# deployment client-web
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "deployment-client-web" {
  metadata {
    name = var.data-deployment-client-web.metadata.name
    labels = {
      App = var.data-deployment-client-web.labels.App
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        App = var.data-deployment-client-web.labels.App
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          App = var.data-deployment-client-web.labels.App
        }
      }

      spec {
        container {
          image = var.data-deployment-client-web.image.name
          command = var.data-deployment-client-web.container.command
          name  = var.data-deployment-client-web.container.name
          port {
            container_port = var.data-deployment-client-web.container.port
          }

          liveness_probe {
            http_get {
              path = "/"
              port = var.data-deployment-client-web.container.port
            }

            initial_delay_seconds = 300
            period_seconds = 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "service-client-web" { # wget http://name-service-server:8000/swagger
  metadata {
    name = var.data-deployment-client-web.service.name
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      App = var.data-deployment-client-web.labels.App
    }
    port {
      port = var.data-deployment-client-web.container.port
    }

    type = var.data-deployment-client-web.service.type
  }
}


# database
resource "google_sql_database" "database" {
  name = "database-profiline-russia"
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.db-instance.name
}

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "db-instance" {
  name = "db-master-instance"
  region = "europe-west3"
  database_version = "POSTGRES_11"
  settings {
    tier = "db-f1-micro"
  }
}

resource "google_sql_user" "db-user" {
  name = "..."
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.db-instance.name
  password = "..."
}


resource "kubernetes_secret" "secret-db" {
  metadata {
    name = "name-secret-db"
  }

  data = {
    db_username = google_sql_user.db-user.name
    db_password = google_sql_user.db-user.password
    db_name = google_sql_database.database.name
  }

  type = "Opaque"
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "secret-gsa" {
  metadata {
    name = "name-secret-gsa"
  }

  data = {
    "service_account.json" = file(var.cred-sa-default)
  }

  type = "Opaque"
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "secret-sa-cloud-storage" {
  metadata {
    name = "name-secret-sa-cloud-storage"
  }

  data = {
    "sa-cloud-storage.json" = file(var.cred-sa-cloud-storage)
  }

  type = "Opaque"
}
```

vars.tf

```
variable "default-bucket-name" {
  type = string
  description = "default bucket name(bucket doesnt recreated(created previously by hands))"
}

variable "database-cloud-sql-name" {
  type = string
  description = "full database name"
}

variable "project-gcp-id" {
  type = string
  description = "gcp project id"
}

variable "cred-sa-default" {
  type = string
  description = "default service account credentials file"
}

variable "cred-sa-cloud-storage" {
  type = string
  description = "cloud storage service account credentials file"
}

variable "data-deployment-server" {
    type = object({
        metadata = object({
            name = string
        })
        image = object({
            name = string
        })
        labels = object({
            App = string
        })
        container = object({
            name = string
            command = list(string)
            port = number
        })
        service = object({
            name = string
            type = string
        })
    })
}

variable "data-cloud-sql-proxy" {
    type = object({
        image = object({
            name = string
        })
        container = object({
            name = string
            command = list(string)
        })
        volume = object({
            name = string
        })
    })
}

variable "data-deployment-client-web" {
    type = object({
        metadata = object({
            name = string
        })
        image = object({
            name = string
        })
        labels = object({
            App = string
        })
        container = object({
            name = string
            command = list(string)
            port = number
        })
        service = object({
            name = string
            type = string
        })
    })
}
```

terraform.tfvars has values of private vars

error in gitlab ci container:

```
 $ terraform apply -auto-approve
 kubernetes_secret.secret-sa-cloud-storage: Refreshing state... [id=default/name-secret-sa-cloud-storage]
 kubernetes_secret.secret-gsa: Refreshing state... [id=default/name-secret-gsa]
 module.kubernetes_dashboard.kubernetes_secret.kubernetes_dashboard_certs: Refreshing state... [id=kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-certs]
 module.kubernetes_dashboard.kubernetes_namespace.kubernetes_dashboard[0]: Refreshing state... [id=kubernetes-dashboard]
 module.kubernetes_dashboard.kubernetes_service.kubernetes_dashboard: Refreshing state... [id=kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard]
 module.kubernetes_dashboard.kubernetes_service_account.kubernetes_dashboard: Refreshing state... [id=kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard]
 module.kubernetes_dashboard.kubernetes_cluster_role.kubernetes_dashboard: Refreshing state... [id=kubernetes-dashboard]
 module.kubernetes_dashboard.kubernetes_cluster_role_binding.kubernetes_dashboard: Refreshing state... [id=kubernetes-dashboard]
 module.kubernetes_dashboard.kubernetes_role.kubernetes_dashboard: Refreshing state... [id=kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard]
 module.kubernetes_dashboard.kubernetes_secret.kubernetes_dashboard_csrf: Refreshing state... [id=kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf]
 module.kubernetes_dashboard.kubernetes_config_map.kubernetes_dashboard_settings: Refreshing state... [id=kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-settings]
 google_container_cluster.primary: Refreshing state... [id=projects/profiline-russia/locations/europe-west3/clusters/main-cluster]
 module.kubernetes_dashboard.kubernetes_service.kubernetes_metrics_scraper: Refreshing state... [id=kubernetes-dashboard/dashboard-metrics-scraper]
 kubernetes_service.service-server: Refreshing state... [id=default/name-service-server]
 google_sql_database_instance.db-instance: Refreshing state... [id=db-master-instance]
 kubernetes_service.service-client-web: Refreshing state... [id=default/name-service-client-web]
 module.kubernetes_dashboard.kubernetes_role_binding.kubernetes_dashboard: Refreshing state... [id=kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard]
 module.kubernetes_dashboard.kubernetes_secret.kubernetes_dashboard_key_holder: Refreshing state... [id=kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder]
 google_sql_user.db-user: Refreshing state... [id=username//db-master-instance]
 google_sql_database.database: Refreshing state... [id=projects/profiline-russia/instances/db-master-instance/databases/database-profiline-russia]
 module.kubernetes_dashboard.kubernetes_deployment.kubernetes_dashboard: Refreshing state... [id=kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard]
 module.kubernetes_dashboard.kubernetes_deployment.kubernetes_metrics_scraper: Refreshing state... [id=kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-metrics-scraper]
 kubernetes_deployment.deployment-client-web: Refreshing state... [id=default/deployment-client-web]
 google_container_node_pool.primary_nodes: Refreshing state... [id=projects/profiline-russia/locations/europe-west3/clusters/main-cluster/nodePools/node-pool]
 kubernetes_secret.secret-db: Refreshing state... [id=default/name-secret-db]
 Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/serviceaccounts/kubernetes-dashboard": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/dashboard-metrics-scraper": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/deployments/kubernetes-dashboard": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/deployment-client-web": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/secrets/kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/name-service-client-web": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/deployments/kubernetes-metrics-scraper": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/name-secret-gsa": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterrolebindings/kubernetes-dashboard": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterroles/kubernetes-dashboard": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/roles/kubernetes-dashboard": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/secrets/kubernetes-dashboard-certs": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/name-service-server": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/kubernetes-dashboard": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/name-secret-sa-cloud-storage": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/secrets/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/rolebindings/kubernetes-dashboard": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/name-secret-db": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
 Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/configmaps/kubernetes-dashboard-settings": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
Running after_script
00:01
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:02
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: in my main.tf file section dashboard commended, after applying this locally and running the same script in container errors with dashboard will dissapear

Answer (score 2):

make sure that in the kubernetes provider configuration `load_config_file` is `false` if you dont use a local config file. this fix the error in my case.

```yaml
load_config_file = false # when you wish not to load the local config file
```

Comment: load_config_file is not supported in kubernetes provider version 2.0.0 and up.

Comment: Yes Jason and then how do you then?

Answer (score 1):

For the kubernetes provider version 2.0.0 and up, in the kubernetes provider section, drop the usage of `config_path` attribute entirely (not even `config_path = "/dev/null"`).

Comment: What if the config_path setting does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when your cluster is not present/available for some reason, and so when planning reaches the kubernetes provider there’s no known cluster endpoint and so that provider is defaulting to connecting to localhost.